# Octave on Windows 10 Cannot install package with Forge

Tags: windows, octave, forge

I am trying to install a few packages with forge on octave. Unfortunately, each time I run

```
pkg install -forge communications
```

I got the following error message:

```
error: get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection
```

It is very confusing for me at this point, and I have checked my Windows Firewall, and it is not blocking my Octave. I am wondering if there is anything I can do about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Octave is 4.2.0 now.  Official Windows binary installer includes a lot of packages. Communications package are included too. You can resolve your problem by downloading installer for Windows - **octave-4.2.0-w64-installer.exe** [download](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/)